# TCP ReceiveBufferSize maximum size in .Net Framework

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I'm trying to use the TCP/Sockets function inside System.Net.Sockets to transfer files.
But, when I try to dynamicaly set the size of the buffer on the client and on the server if the size is less that 4096, the transfert done well but if it's more than 4096, the buffer keep the 4096 value and so the file is not received completly.

So, I was wondering ? Is this the maximum value ? 
If yes, Is it safe to use a Buffer which is fulled by a loop on the client and received with the same method on the server ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a similar and very simple file receiver with sockets once (just to try sockets, so the code isn't all that pretty):

```
  Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2442);
  socket.Bind(endpoint);
  socket.Listen(10000);
  System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming data on *:2442");
  Socket client = socket.Accept();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
  List<byte> wholeThing = new List<byte>();
  int count = 0;
  do {
    count = client.Receive(buffer);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
      wholeThing.Add(buffer[i]);
    System.Console.Write("*");
  } while (count > 0);
  System.Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Received {0} bytes of data", wholeThing.Count);
  File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\\receivedFile", wholeThing.ToArray());
```

The sender code looked like this:

```
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(targetip), 2442);
    int offset = 0;
    do {
      try {
        offset = socket.Send(fileData, offset, fileData.Length - offset, SocketFlags.None);
      } catch {
        socket.Close();
        throw;
      }
    } while (offset < fileData.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send larger files .net commonly breaks them up into smaller chunks. You need to reassemble the data as it is received, piece by piece, at the client end. I think the ConnectionPacketBuilder class in [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net), line 134 [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/v0.1/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs) achieves what you want to do. You can see how it is used as data comes in around line 793.